# Find/ Match in a particular row of a particular sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to match a text/ string in Row 1 of a different workbook and sheet and return (`wb.Worksheets(cmb)`) its column number. 
My code copies a column from a spreadsheet to another:

```
If Form.ComboBox4.Value <> "" Then
        Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns("E")
        Set targetColumn = Workbooks("B.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Columns("C")
        sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End If
```

Typically, I want to do something like:

```
wb.Worksheets(cmb).Match(Form.ComboBox2.Value, Rows(1))
```

This doesnt work because obviously, the syntax is wrong. 
What is the right way to do this? **If the value (`Form.ComboBox2.Value`) matches, I want it to return the corresponding column number of the resulting match ** that I can substitute here `wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns("E")`

This is how the sheet looks like:

[image]

Say if `Form.ComboBox2.Value` = '`ITEM.`', Then it should return '`A`'

Comment: Use `wb.Sheets(cmb).Rows(1).Find(Form.ComboBox2.Value).Column`

Comment: `OutputColumn = Application.Match(Form.ComboBox2.Value,wb.Worksheets(cmb).Rows(1),0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner: This returns column number instead of the alphabet. ie: returns 2 instead of 'B'

Comment: @tigeravatar This returns column number instead of the alphabet. ie: returns 2 instead of 'B'

Comment: Typically you want it to return the number, not the letter. If it absolutely must be the letter, this will work for you: `Replace(wb.Worksheets(cmb).Rows(1).Find(FormComboBox2Value).Address(0, 0), "1", vbNullString)`

Comment: Columns also allows for and index; `Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns(OutputColumn)`